# Mockito mockStatic cannot resolve symbol

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

I'm using Spring Boot and in a unit test, I'm trying to mock the `Files.delete(myFile.toPath())` method.
To do so I'm trying to use the `Mockito.mockStatic()` method. But when I try to use it my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) indicate me that this method does not exist.
I read this article :
https://asolntsev.github.io/en/2020/07/11/mockito-static-methods/
but it didn't help me.

In my POM.xml file there is:

```yaml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.15</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.15</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Note that I only put test related dependency, this is not my whole POM.xml file

In my test file, I put the following imports:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
```

Again, this is only the test related imports.

A screenshot of what my IDE is displaying:
[image]

Do you have any idea why the `Mockito.mockStatic()` method can't be resolved ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make sure you have the following dependency in your pom file

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.15</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you ! It worked ! The article was saying to replace `mockito-core` by `mockito-inline`, I should have tried to put both.

Comment: Yep, i got the same thing.  Thanks

Comment: Adding this dependency, now I can't resolve `Mockito.Matchers`

Comment: use Mockito.ArgumentMatchers

Answer (score -1):

Probably the method is inside your class scope, move the static method call `mockStatic` to method scope.

Also be sure you're importing from this class  `org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the question was about the Mockito framework which is different from PowerMockito.