# Mockito cannot resolve a public static method of a class

Tags: spring, mocking, mockito, junit4, mockstatic

I have a `Component` class called `AppUtil` with a bunch of `public` `static` methods:

```java
@Component
public class AppUtil {
    
    // Methods, fields...
    
    public static List<String> getActiveProfiles() {
        return newArrayList(appUtil.env.getActiveProfiles());
    }

    public static String readResourceFileAsString(String fileName) throws IOException {
        return IOUtils.toString(new FileReader(fileName));
    }
    
    // More methods....
    
}
```

The two `static` methods writen above are called by a method called `loadUserByUsername` of a class called `GearApiUserDetailsService`. In order to test `GearApiUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername`, I want to mock the calls to these `static` methods of `AppUtil`. This is what my unit testing class looks like right now:

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class GearApiUserDetailsServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private GearApiUserDetailsService gearApiUserDetailsService;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testLoadUserByUsernameWithoutActiveProfiles(){
        try (MockedStatic<AppUtil> mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(AppUtil.class)) {
            mockedStatic.when(AppUtil::getActiveProfiles).thenReturn(Collections.emptyList());
            mockedStatic.when(AppUtil::readResourceFileAsString).thenReturn("random string");
            final String apiKey = "someExampleAPIKey"; 
            UserDetails userDetails = gearApiUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(apiKey);
            assertEquals(apiKey, userDetails.getUsername());
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that while the mock of `getActiveProfiles` works well (tested), the mock of `readResourceFileAsString` fails at ***compile*** time even, with IntelliJ reporting that it can't resolve it:

[image]

The methods are both `public` and `static`, with the only difference being that the second one takes an argument.

[This 2020 post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64461915/mockito-mockstatic-cannot-resolve-symbol) seems to suggest ensuring that the `pom` file contains a dependency of `mockito-core` at version `3.5.13`. I have included this dependency, invalidated caches / restarted, tried to re-run entire maven build lifecycle, but obviously it still fails at compile time because of the aforementioned error. Ideas? (=

Answer (score 1):

I was able to determine, through a [very recent Baeldung entry](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods), that when one mocks static methods with arguments, one has to use an instance of the functional interface `MockedStatic.Verification`, which can be the target of a lambda expression. So, changing this:

```
mockedStatic.when(AppUtil::readResourceFileAsString).thenReturn("random string");
```

to:

```java
mockedStatic.when(() -> AppUtil.readResourceFileAsString(anyString())).thenReturn("random string");
```

did the trick. Marking this answer accepted after necessary 24 hour period.